# Configure the ext-mail of hudson

Tags: grails, hudson, findbugs, cobertura, jelly

I have a grails project and I use hudson to follow different analysis. I want to send the report analysis (cobertura, codenarc, findbug) to the developer. However, I don't know how to use hudson's ext-mail. Through googling I suspect the solution is to use jelly sscript but I can seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

If the default jelly templates don't have everything you need in them, you can customize them without much effort.

1. Grab a copy of the default template: [Default Jelly Templates](https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/tree/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates)
2. Modify it as needed
3. Place a copy in JENKINS_HOME\email-templates (create the dir if needed)
4. Configure the build to utilize the new template. If your new script is ensienne.jelly, the email content would look like this ${JELLY_SCRIPT,template="ensienne"}.

Side Note: Hudson was renamed to Jenkins a while back.

Also, here is a good resource for the email-ext plugin: [Email-ext wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin)

Comment: Thank you for answering me. In the html.jelly file there is many part (junit, build, artifact, cobertura). How can I specify that I want only the cobertura part. in addition how can I configure this part to point my resultfolder.

Comment: You should be able to update the jelly script and remove the parts you dont want. Within your build config you may configure the cobertura locations.